# Listing available drivers in intake

Tags: python, python-3.x, driver, intake

How can I list all the available drivers in `intake`?

I attempted to run `dir` on `intake.source`, but didn't manage to find a listing of drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python:

```
from intake.source import registry
list(registry)
```

In shell

```
> intake drivers list
```

Most sources will also get an `intake.open_...` function created at import time, but check out the `intake.sources.discovery` module to see how these drivers are located. Some may be disables in the config.

Also, you can refer to any driver explicitly by its package.module.Class in a data source, you do not need to have a given driver registered.